# How to collaborate code in real time?

Tags: text-editor, sharing, source-code

A friend of mine needs me to give him some tutoring in Python, mind it needs to be done **online**. Is there an application or service where we can both see the code, as he is writing it, that is in **realtime**?

We tried sharing screen in Skype but video quality is utterly low.

He is using Windows, I am using Windows and Ubuntu. Either way, I need something to share screen/code changes in real time. We have an audio connection already so we only need that.

Comment: OneNote? Word? Google Docs? I don't see what this has to do with Ubuntu though.

Comment: You could do screensharing through TeamViewer.

Comment: You may use a private reprostory on gitlab and Teamspeak / skype for voice comunitation.

Comment: This might get you started: [Is there a way to use Google Docs for collaborative programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617527/is-there-a-way-to-use-google-docs-for-collaborative-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028358/real-time-tool-for-collaborative-coding) was rolled through already.

My favorite tool that I found: http://codr.io/